# como criar uma nova branch no GitHub?

Tags: github, branch

Gostaria de saber como criar uma nova *branch* no GitHub

Já tenho a branch master criada e não vi nenhuma opção "create branch", alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Além da opção Doougui, você pode usar comando no terminal:

```
git checkout -b MinhaNovaBrach
```

Depois, quando quiser subir a branch, faça os commits:

```
git commit -m 'Comentário do commit da minha nova branch'
```

Depois, subindo de fato:

```
git push --set-upstream origin MinhaNovaBrach
```

Recomendo ler esse guia: https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Comment: Se tiver preguiça de digitar `--set-upstream`, a opção curta equivalente é `-u`

Answer (score 7):

Abra o seu repositório no GitHub logado em sua conta e clique na opção "branch" como mostrado na imagem abaixo. Após isso é só digitar o nome da branch no campo e o mesmo vai ser criado automaticamente.

[image: Criando branch no GitHub]

Comment: vlw pela ajuda, deu certo!

Comment: @Schielke já que essa é a resposta que atende à sua questão, então marque-a como aceita clicando no ✅ ao lado esquerdo

Answer (score 5):

Também pelo terminal:

Para criar a nova branch a partir da branch que você está:

```
git branch MinhaNovaBrach
```

Para criar a nova branch a partir de uma branch especifica:

```
git branch -c branchEspecifica MinhaNovaBrach
```

Nos dois casos você precisa trocar para a branch criada, commitar e fazer o trancking:

```
git checkout MinhaNovaBrach

git commit -m "Olha que commit lindo <3"

git push -u origin MinhaNovaBrach
```